# add multiband rasters in r

Tags: r, sum, raster

i'm working with landsat data doing some topographic corrections using the method proposed by Hantson & Chuvieco (2010) which involves a cover separation method based on a certain NDVI value to tell between vegetated and non-vegetated areas.

So, I go from having one multiband raster object to two, which are processed sepparately and subsequently combined to form the original, topographically corrected, scene.

The problem is that I have some NA values in the scene, so if I don't get rid of them I get a blank image as a result. I use the `sum` function with the `na.rm` option defined as TRUE to tackle this problem, but the result is a one-band raster object instead of a stack or rasterbrick object.

This is my code:

```
#topographic correction
VEGB1TC<- topocorr(VEGB1,slopeG,aspectG,sunelev,sunazimuth,method="ccorrection",na.value=NA)
VEGB2TC<- topocorr(VEGB2,slopeG,aspectG,sunelev,sunazimuth,method="ccorrection",na.value=NA)
....        
SDB1TC<- topocorr(SDB1,slopeG,aspectG,sunelev,sunazimuth,method="ccorrection",na.value=NA)
SDB2TC<- topocorr(SDB2,slopeG,aspectG,sunelev,sunazimuth,method="ccorrection",na.value=NA)
...

#rasterize corrected band and stack them 
VB1<-raster(VEGB1TC)
VB2<-raster(VEGB2TC)
....

ADEVEG<-stack(VB1, VB2,...)

SB1<-raster(SDB1TC)
SB2<-raster(SDB2TC)
....

ADESD<-stack(SB1, SB2,...)

#-----------combine images-------

ADE<-sum(stack(ADEVEG,ADESD),na.rm=T)
```

Is there a function that can add multiband rasters with a `na.rm` tag? I've found the `do.call` function but it seems to me that it sums several rasters into a single-band object.

Thanks for your help.

ps: Hantson, S. Chuvieco, E. 2010. Evaluation of different topographic correction methods for Landsat imagery. International Journal of Applied Earth Observations and Geoinformation 13(2011):691-700p.

Comment: If you sum a number of raster layers you will get one band only. Or do you want to sum stacks ADEVEG and ADESD separately and then stack them? May be you want to do is `ADE<-stack(sum(ADEVEG,na.rm=T),sum(ADESD,na.rm=T))`

Comment: I want to fuse the two stacks into one as they represent the barren and vegetated portions of a scene, combining the multiple bands at the same time. In the end I just replaced NA vaues with 0 manualy and then proceed to add both stacks by simple adition. Your method is not what I intend but thanks a lot for the quick answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(raster)
s1 <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
s2 <- flip(s1, 'x')
s2[1000:4000] <- NA
```

Now you can do:

```
r1 <- s1 + s2
```

But that does not take care of `NA` values. So do you would need to resort to something like:

```
r2 <- overlay(s1, s2, fun=function(x) sum(x, na.rm=TRUE))
```

or this:

```
s2r <- reclassify(s2, cbind(NA, 0))
r3 <- s1 + s2r
```

PS. I understand that expected `sum(s1, s2)` to return a multi-layered object, but I think returning one layer is consistent with `base::sum`:

```
sum(1:4, 1:4)
# [1] 20
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. In the end I just replaced the NA values using x[is.na(x[])] <- 0 for each of the multiband rasters and then combine them into one by simple adition (x3<- x1 + x2).

This works for me fine but I was just wondering if there would be a more automatized way to sum two rasters and deal with the NA presence.

Comment: you should not do `x[is.na(x[])] <- 0` (risky memory-wise); perhaps do `x[is.na(x)] <- 0`, but `reclassify` is preferable,